# USB 802.11g Wi-Fi adapter that's compatible with Windows XP 64-bit

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, wireless-networking

Does anyone know of a USB Wi-Fi adapter that is compatible with Windows XP 64-bit?  It must support at least 802.11g and Cisco WLAN extensions.  Due to the specific hardware it must be USB and I cannot upgrade to Vista or 7 64-bit.  I haven't had much luck with searching on Amazon or Newegg.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Belkin USB adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833314011&cm_re=usb_802.11g-_-33-314-011-_-Product) has drivers for XP 64-bit on the [Belkin support web site](http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/297/kw/F5D7050/r_id/166).

Comment: Even though Newegg and Amazon do not yet list the newest 5XXX revision of the hardware that is the most current model according to the driver page, I'll keep my eye on this one as it does have the necessary drivers.  I may not be able to get on the private network without the Cisco Extensions, but at least I'll be able to continue on with my work using the guest network.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[DWL-G122 High Speed 2.4GHz (802.11g) Wireless USB Adapter](http://www.d-link.com/products/?pid=334) has drivers for XP 64-bit here - [drivers](ftp://files.dlink.com.au/products/DWL-G122/REV_C/Drivers/). I don't know about Cisco extensions unfortunatelly (don't even know what they are).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That particular product was marked end-of-life in 2007, so that likely means eBay which the Powers That Be at work frown upon.  FYI, here is more information on Cisco Extensions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Compatible_EXtensions